# Onboarding screen does not work correctly with auth Firebase in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

The logic of the application - onboading screen appears only once, after it goes to the authorization screen with Firebase. If the authorization is successful, we open the home page of the application.

But this doesn't work the first time you run the app. After hot restart app - the login is done and we are right back to the home page.

Is there any way to fix it? (And without onboarding this logic works)

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final showHome = pref.getBool('showHome') ?? false;
  runApp(MyApp(showHome: showHome));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool showHome;
  MyApp({Key? key, required this.showHome}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      ...
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return errorMessage();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const BottomPage();
            } else {
              return showHome ? const LoginPage() : const Onboarding();
            }
          },
        ),
}
```

LoginPage()

```
try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _loginController.text.trim(),
        password: _passwordContoller.text.trim(),
      );
    }
```

Onboarding()

```
onTap: () async {
   final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   pref.setBool('showHome', true);

   Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginPage()));
},
```

Comment: Hi, struggling with the same issue, did you find a solution?